# How to reset BIOS softpaq on HP EliteBook?

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

I bought HP 8560p from my friend. He managed to make a mess, by trying to install Manjaro (something got wrong with CMOS and HD). Later he provided me with bootable USB but it is not recognized by laptop.

I found https://support.hp.com/rs-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-8560p-notebook-pc/5056949.

How can I reset or reinstall initial BIOS configuration from scratch?

[image]

What should I do step by step?

Comment: One does not install BIOS on a machine.  It sounds like you just want to restore the defaults, you can do that, from within the BIOS itself.  Have you tried dong that?

Comment: Take a look at my edit,please.How to restore defaults?

Comment: It isn't in the system diagnostic screen.  If you are only able to get to the system diagnostics screen and are unable to change the firmware configuration, then you will be unable to reset the firmware configuration.  Your edit has done very little to make your question clear.

Comment: [How to Restore the BIOS on HP Computers with a Key Press Combination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpiGUojtr3E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first step you should reset the BIOS, which can only be done within the BIOS
itself.

This can be done by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> during the boot, and when a boot
menu appears typing <kbd>F10</kbd>.

If this only brings you to the System Diagnostics screen, you will need to
open the laptop and unplug the CMOS battery and wait for some minutes.
After plugging it back in, you may be able to access the BIOS.